# What determines if an upgrade circuit can or cannot be sold?

Tags: dead-space-3

I recently got this message after trying to sell an upgrade circuit that I'm not gonna be using anymore:

[image: "Circuit cannot be sold!" on a +3 Damage Circuit]

What determines if an upgrade circuit can or cannot be sold? Is there a way to make these unsellable circuits, sellable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you cannot sell circuit with +3 stats. This is a bit silly as you may end up with a lot of +3/+2 when you already have +3/+3.

You end up having to scroll through huge lists due to this...